# OSX: How to easily view thumbnails of lots of images in an S3 bucket

Tags: image, macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, thumbnails

In my company we need to share images with clients. This is done via S3 buckets, using Transmit to upload the images.

The administrators want to be able to see thumbnail images of all the images. I thought mounting the bucket and viewing it in Finder would work (I imagined that Finder would cache the thumbnails after visiting for the first time) but it only works with small numbers of images, not thousands. It doesn't seem to cache the Thumbnails and takes a long time to generate them. (Also tried this using ExpanDrive, which had the same issues).

Anyone got a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an automated capability in Amazon S3 to display thumbnails of files within S3 buckets.

One option, as you have done, is to mount an Amazon S3 bucket as a drive and have the operating system display pictures, but this requires a lot of communication between your computer and S3 because it actually needs to download each picture.

Or, you could download all the pictures to a local drive by using the `aws s3 sync` command from the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). That way, things will work faster (but with the downside of having to download all the files).

An alternative would be to write a small program web app (possibly just a JavaScript page) that obtains a list of all pictures and then displays them in the browser. You can create thumbnails "on-the-fly" using services like [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) or [Imgix](https://www.imgix.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Usually, we don't like tool requests on StackOverflow. Bot here you have a nice list:

- [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io) It supports S3 connections. Also as paid version in the App Store.
- [MCSTools-s3 (App Store)](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/mcstools-s3/id814517168?l=en&mt=12)
- [3hub (App Store)](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/3hub/id427515976?l=en&mt=12)
- [Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com)

Also make sure to have google searched for "s3 browser mac"

Comment: ok, but this isn't necessarily a tool request. None of the products you link to solve the issue. I am trying to solve a technical problem, which I believe is mainly related to how OSX caches thumbnail images on network/external drives. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Hmm... The used tool would need to calculate small thumbnails and cache them their self. I would have thought these tools would do it, but you'r right, I didn't understand the core issue in the first moment – sorry ;)

Comment: In the worst case you could create a _REALLY_ simple OS X application that does this task. It shouldn't be too complicated, I think. Stay watching this: https://github.com/julian-weinert/simpleBucketList

Comment: Nothing there yet but I'll do a bit the next few evenings

Comment: Wow Julian, that will be wonderful. I will keep an eye on it. I'm sure there are other people that would find this useful.

Comment: Looking forwards to it!

Comment: I already have some basic stuff in there. Unfortunately AWS does not offer an OS X SDK, so I decided to create a Node.js wrapper that gets compiled at build time. If you are interested in (and able to) contributing, I'd be really happy :))

Comment: Google brought me here xD

Comment: does cyberduck do thumbnail previews ?

Comment: no thumbnail review for all of them